# Semi-rich formatted text display options in WPF

Tags: wpf, behavior, flowdocument, richtext

My WPF application has content displayed on a panel. The content will be authored content, hence it has to be somewhat standards compliant (like HTML or markdown or maybe even XAML etc.)
The content will have formatted text, such as bold, italic and it can have hyperlinks and tooltips.

My questions:

1. What would be the appropriate text format to use?
2. And what will be the best option to implement behaviors? I tried using RTF, but how do I open the browser when the user clicks on a url within the RTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried hosting the text in a RichTextBox?  This uses XAML to back the text but there are conversions to RTF or HTML.  The article [Mastering the WPF RichTextBox](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/34644/1954) may be useful.

Comment: I ended up using a FlowDocumentScrollviewer for the display and FlowDocument for the content. For the behavior, the Hyperlink.Click method provided what I needed. Tooltips are directly supported in Flowdocuments.

Comment: @Gemini: No worries.  BTW because your final solution is different from my answer its perfectly acceptable to add an answer your self and accept that (no one looks down on this - plus if people find your aswer useful they will vote it up and you'll get rep) - so feel free to do that.